# variable-sized object may not be initialized confusion

Tags: c++, arrays, random

The below code is attempting to randomly initialize array z of  0 or 1. I receive the following error message

error: variable-sized object may
      not be initialized
int z[x]= rand()%2;

1 error generated.
isn't Z size given as 10?

```
 int z[10];
     for(int x =0; x <=(sizeof(z) / sizeof(z[0]));x++)
     {
            srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
            int z[x]= rand()%2;
            std ::cout<<z[x];
     }
```

Comment: `s/int z[x]/z[x]/`

Answer (score 0):

`int z[x]` looks like a variable definition, rather than an assignment.

Remove the `int` to make this:

```
z[x]= rand()%2;
```

Additionally, you only have to seed the random number generator once using `srand`, so move that to before your loop

Answer (score 0):

Inside for loop change `int z[x]= rand()%2;` into `z[x]= rand()%2;`. Look I remove `int` from there.